# Plotting an array by calling it from its string name in a for-loop - Python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, arraylist

Having different lists called for example:

```
A_foo = [1, 2, 3]
B_foo = [4, 5, 6]
```

I want to generate a for loop over the list of strings `["A", "B"]` in order to print/recall the array with that name.

```
for i in ["A", "B"]:
    #print (i)  
    x = i + '_foo'
    print("%s" % x)
```

Output: A_foo, B_foo but I would like to get -
np.array([1, 2, 3])
np.array([4, 5, 6])
instead.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Better to work with a dict, e.g. `{'A':A_foo, 'B':B_foo}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code cannot work the way you want.

You should not try to generate/access variable names dynamically. This is an anti-pattern.

Instead, use a dictionary:

```
data = {'A_foo': [1, 2, 3],
        'B_foo': [4, 5, 6]}

for i in ["A", "B"]:
    x = f'{i}_foo'
    print(x, data[x])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could access the [globals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) dictionary as in the example below. However, this is not a good approach. A better way would be by using the proper data structure, like a dictionary in this case, as in @mozway answer.

```
A_foo = [1, 2, 3]
B_foo = [4, 5, 6]

for i in ["A", "B"]:
    print(i, globals()[f'{i}_foo'])


A [1, 2, 3]
B [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: please don't suggest this to beginners, this is really a bad approach

Comment: I agree, let me specify it in the answer